# jQuery mobile title position with button

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a simple app that I am running on an iPhone (iOS 5), which doesn't properly size and position the back button and the header text.  The header text winds up being underneath the button.  I guess jQuery Mobile doesn't size/position things as expected out of the box...

What I am after is that the header text gets truncated and starts to the right of the back button.  There won't be another button to the right of the title, so it is fine if it goes to the right of the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css"/>        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>    </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <a data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">A long button</a>
                    <h1>A very very very long title</h1>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <p>Page content goes here.</p>   
                </div>

                <div data-role="footer">
                    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

A runnable example is at: http://jsfiddle.net/5n8WN/

I did look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262667/aligning-the-jquery-mobile-header-title) but what I did try didn't get me what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your title is being covered is that there is a `90px` margin on the right/left of the `H1` tag and your back button is larger than `90px`. You can change the CSS rules for the `.ui-title` class to fix this:

```
.ui-title {
    margin     : 0.6em 1em 0.8em 140px !important;
    text-align : left !important;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/5n8WN/1/

Answer (score 2):

> **Custom header configurations** 
>   If you need to to create a header that doesn't follow the default configuration, simply wrap your custom
>   styled markup in a container div inside the header container and the
>   plugin won't apply the automatic button logic so you can write custom
>   styles for laying out the content in your header.
>
> It's also possible to create custom bars without using the header
>   data-role at all. For example, start with any container and add the
>   ui-bar class to apply standard bar padding and add the ui-bar-b class
>   to assign the bar swatch styles from your theme (the "b" can be any
>   swatch letter).

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Eample:

```
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">
    <h3>I'm just a div with bar classes and a <a href="#" data-role="button">Button</a></h3>
</div>
```