# JQuery Mobile Header alignment going haywire

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

With JQueryM, I am trying to develop a header that is supposed to look like this

---

|[menu-icon] tickets (left aligned)------------------[search-icon][plus-icon]

---

My markup is as such

```
       <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-menu"></a>
            <h1 align="left">tickets</h1>

            <a href="#page-new-ticket" id="btn-new-ticket" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-search" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a>                         
            <a href="#page-new-ticket" id="btn-new-ticket" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a> 
        </div>
```

This apparently doesnt produce the required results. I have tried a lot of ways including
[Aligning the Jquery mobile header title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262667/aligning-the-jquery-mobile-header-title)

and

```
.ui-title {
        margin     : 0.6em 1em  50px !important;
        text-align : left !important;}
```

But now I have reached a place where I seem lost. Can anyone please take a look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, **HTML**:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a class="ui-btn-left" data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-menu"></a>
    <h1 class="ui-btn-left spacerleft" >tickets</h1>

    <a class="ui-btn-right spacerright" href="#page-new-ticket" id="btn-new-ticket" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a>                         
    <a class="ui-btn-right" href="#page-new-ticket" id="btn-new-ticket" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"></a> 
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.spacerleft
{
    margin-left: 50px !important;
}
.spacerright
{
    margin-right: 50px !important;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3KQN/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this(it's a quickly answer):

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div style="float:left"><a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-menu"></a></div>
    <div style="float:left"><h3>tickets</h3></div>
    <div style="float:left;padding-left: 6em; ">
        <a href="#page-new-ticket" data-direction="reverse" id="btn-new-ticket" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-search" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="false"></a>
        <a href="#page-new-ticket" id="btn-new-ticket" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="false"></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```